# Economic options of health insurance for a foreigner student in germany

Tags: germany, health-insurance

I'm a foreigner student who will do a master's degree in germany but as you know I need a health insurance plan. I looked up a little and found out that there are various options. One of them is AOK but it's 83 euros fee (aprox) which seems too much for me so I'd like to know in your experience which are the best economic options for students.

Comment: For below 100 Euros you can get a top-notch health insurance that covers everything in case you need it? Take it. You won't get a better deal price/value wise (for Germany, and almost anywhere else in the world).

Answer (score 2):

[Bar some exceptions](http://www.internationale-studierende.de/gerade_angekommen/krankenversicherung/) (that likely do not apply and that I would not advise you to make use of even if they did) you have to sign up for a "gesetzliche Krankenversicherung" ([statutory health insurance as opposed to private](https://www.mawista.com/kvfas/)).

The monthly fee (and service) [varies very little between the different insurers](https://www.krankenkassen.de/meine-krankenkasse/student/ausland/) and you will need to accept that cost as part of your studies. In exchange you get good health care that is fairly cheap (you are effectively receiving subsidies from the other participants in the insurance scheme that pay a percentage of their salary instead, typically much more than 83 EUR a month).

Comment: (+1) FYI: One common translation for “gesetzliche Krankenversicherung” is “statutory health insurance”. Also, €83 is not too expensive compared to private insurance or the US system, but AFAIK in the ballpark of neighbouring countries so not really “*extremely* cheap compared to *about anywhere else*”. As a comparison, insurance is free in France if you qualify for state support (even for foreign students), about the same price in the Netherlands (and there is also a special subsidy available for low incomes), free at the point of use in the UK anyway, etc.

Comment: And the German healthcare system is just fine but usually in the middle of the pack/lower half of the EU in performance rankings. Again, better than, say, African countries but not really “top notch” among its peers.

Comment: @Gala thanks, suggestions implemented. Next time please go ahead and edit right away, I appreciate that.